# Buildroot failed, but I can't get why

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi3, buildroot

I try to build a raspberry pi image using dockerized buildroot, but it fails on a message I can't understand:

```
echo '' > /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/stamp.oST
mv -f /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/stamp.osT /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/stamp.os
mv -f /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/stamp.oST /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/stamp.oS
/opt/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc sdlfreeres.c -c -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline  -Wno-error -O2 -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Werror -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -fno-stack-protector -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -fmath-errno      -ftls-model=initial-exec      -I../include -I/opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn  -I/opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm  -I../sysdeps/arm/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/arm  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/arm/include -I../sysdeps/arm  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I. -nostdinc -isystem /opt/buildroot/output/host/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/9.2.0/include -isystem /opt/buildroot/output/host/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/9.2.0/include-fixed -isystem /opt/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -DTOP_NAMESPACE=glibc -o /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/sdlfreeres.o -MD -MP -MF /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/sdlfreeres.o.dt -MT /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/sdlfreeres.o
mv: '/opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/stamp.oST' and '/opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/stamp.oS' are the same file
make[3]: *** [../o-iterator.mk:9: /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build/dlfcn/stamp.oS] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: Leaving directory '/opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/dlfcn'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:259: dlfcn/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/build'
make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:269: /opt/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.30-20-g50f20fe506abb8853641006a7b90a81af21d7b91/.stamp_built] Error 2
```

I use the `raspberrypi3_wpe_2_38_cog_defconfig` config with a simple custom conf (enable `dosfstools`, `mtools`, `ext2/3/4 root filesystem` with an `ext4` by default)

It seems every dependency is present, but it always fails with this obscure message.

I tried building from `buildroot/base:latest` image, then fell back to `buildroot/base:20211120.1925` and also tried with `julianjacobi/buildroot:latest` but it does not work...

Can anyone help, or give me some clues?

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem? We have the same issue currently.

Comment: Sadly, no. I gave up and now use WPE Webkit : https://snapcraft.io/install/wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk/raspbian

Comment: I fixed my problem, my filesystem was case-INsensitive causing the file stamp.os and stamp.Os to be mapped to the same file causing errors. Perhaps you formatted your ext4 case insensitive?